# How to prevent nested form in HTML without having to move the controls

Tags: html

I have .Net Core MVC application written in C# and I have this HTML

```
<form>  
  <input type="text" id="username" />
  <input type="text" id="password" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now I want to put FileUpload between username and password, but I also want to use separate Form and submit for it. How do I achieve this?

Comment: 2 Parallel forms ? Siblings

Comment: @Shyju: Can you provide example?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: BTW, Why do you want to keep the file upload between username and password if it is being submitted with a different submit button ?

Comment: @Shyju: It's just an example, in my real application, I have bunch of field for product information along with its picture.

Comment: What is stopping you from having 2 forms(not nested, but siblings) ?

Comment: @Shyju: I don't understand what do you mean by siblings? Can you be more specific or post an answer with example? The link you gave me have bunch of answers.

Comment: Create another `form` under your current code. That will be a sibling to your current form.

Comment: @Shyju: I want the upload file position to be between username and password.

Comment: You didn't tell us about why you wish to have two separate forms. Have to submit to different servers?